# Finding correspondence of edges for image matching

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, optimization, computer-vision

I have a challenging problem to solve. The [Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCWN6.png) shows green lines, that are derived from an image and the red lines are the edges derived from another image. Both the images are taken from the same camera, so the intrinsic parameters are same. Only, the exterior parameters are different, i.e. there is a slight rotation and translation while taking the 2nd image. As it can be seen in the figure, the two sets of lines are pretty close. My task is to find correspondence between the edges derived from the 1st image and the edges derived from the second image.

I have gone through a few sources, that mention taking corresponding the nearest line segment, by calculating Euclidean distances between the endpoints of an edge of image 1 to the edges of image 2. However, this method is not acceptable for my case, as there are edges in image 1, near to other edges in image 2 that are not corresponding, and this will lead to a huge number of mismatches.

After a bit of more research, few more sources referred to **Hausdorff distance**. I believe that this could really be a solution to my problem and the paper

> "Rucklidge, William J. "Efficiently locating objects using the
>   Hausdorff distance." International Journal of Computer Vision 24.3
>   (1997): 251-270."

seemed to be really interesting.

If, I got it correct the paper formulated a function for calculating translation of model edges to image edges. However, while implementation in MATLAB, I'm completely lost, where to begin. I will be much obliged if I can be directed to a pseudocode of the same algorithm or MATLAB implementation of the same.

Additionally, I am aware of

> "Apply Hausdorff distance to tile image classification" [link](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34531-apply-hausdorf-distance-to-tile-image-classification)

and

> "Hausdorff regression"

However, still, I'm unsure how to minimise Hausdorff distance.

Note1: Computational cost is not of concern now, but faster algorithm is preferred

Note2: I am open to other algorithms and methods to solve this as long as there is a pseudocode available or an open implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered MATLAB's image registration tools?

With imregister(https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imregister.html), you can just insert both images, 1 as reference, one as "moving" and it will register them together using an affine transform. The function call is just

```
[optimizer, metric] = imregconfig('monomodal');
output_registered = imregister(moving,fixed,'affine',optimizer,metric);
```

For better visualization, use the RegistrationEstimator command to open up a gui in which you can import the 2 images and play around with it to register your images. From there you can export code for future images.

Furthermore if you wish to account for non-rigid transforms there is imregdemons(https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imregdemons.html) which works much the same way.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. For my work, I need to match edges extracted from the images, matching images directly is not an option for me.
Still as suggested by you, I tried using the Matlab image registration toolbox on the edge images. Unfortunately, the result was incorrect. 


Later I used the imregdemons function. The output image is same as the input image, except for some distortions in the lines. But still, there is a translation and rotation needed for exact correspondence. But many thanks for your effort and time.

Comment: Does the registration have to be automatic? If not, you may be better off selecting point pairs manually and computing a transform from that.

Comment: Yes, by seIecting pairs of points manually, it can be achieved and if I'm not wrong, 4-5 point pairs around the images are sufficient for the purpose. However, I have to perform this for at least 1000 images, hence I've to find a way of doing it automatically.

Comment: @Debaditya This is the current method I use for my registration
https://github.com/raacampbell/matlab_elastix
Otherwise, there is something called coherent point drift. Note that I never personally got this method to work but it does seem to be more for edges than what I was working with
https://github.com/markeroon/CoherentPointDrift

Something to note if you are new to this is that there is a lot of adjustments to be made to make image registration work properly and you may need to fudge with settings.

Comment: @Debaditya Finally, image registration is a very complex process, I would not advise to try and do it if you do not have experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the Hausdorff distance using Matlab's bwdist function.  You would compute the distance transform of one image, evaluate it at the edge points of the other, and take the maximum value.  (You can also take the sum instead, in which case it is called the chamfer distance.) For this problem you'll probably want the symmetric Hausdorff distance, so you would do the computation in both directions.

Both Hausdorff and chamfer distance measure the match quality of a particular alignment.  To find the best registration you'll need to try multiple alignment transformations and evaluate them all looking for the best one.  As suggested in another answer, you may find it easier to use registration existing tools than to write your own.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I've calculated the distance transform of one image of the pixels corresponding to end points of edges of the other image, and I've also taken the maximum value for each edge. Now I've a distance of for each edge for the other image. My apologies for asking this nieve question, but, how can I create correspondence using this information?

Comment: The bwdist function has a second return value that gives you the index of the closest corresponding pixel.

Comment: Thank you again for your reply. I'll give it a try and will let you know the outcome.

Comment: I was just wondering when you said "try multiple alignment transformations", did you meant that an exhaustive search has to be done for all possible poses (X,Y,Z, omega, phi, kappa)? or there is a better way to optimise search?